# Dealing with StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in if statement Java

Tags: java, runtime-error

I have a program that gets an input from the console. It checks what the input is then using 'if's it decides what to do. One section test to see what the first four letters of the string are, to see if it needs to deal with it, but not all of the strings are always 4 or more letters long. This means that if you type in something that is less than 4 letters long, it encounters an error, and quits. I can't put that section at the end, because at the end there is an else, which if the command is unknown, is called and something happens. Is there a way I can stop the error from occurring?

My code is:

```
if(input.equals("help")){
    int commandsSize = commands.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < commandsSize; i++) {
    String value = commands.get(i);
    System.out.println(value);
} else if((input.substring(0, 4)).equals("open")) {
...
}
```

Comment: Simpler might be `input.startsWith("open")`.

Comment: What error exactly? At what line of code?

Comment: @Bohemian Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4. This is if you put in a string with less than 4 letters

Comment: @r.d then you'd better check the length first, or simply use `.startsWith()` as others have suggested

Comment: @Bohemian ok thanks. For future reference, if I am getting an error in my code should I include it in the question?

Comment: yes, please include error details in the question. "error" can mean lots of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the size of the string the user inputs,

```
if (input.length() != 4) {
  System.out.println("You must enter valid input");
  // Probably do something here. 
}

if(input.equals("help")){
    int commandsSize = commands.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < commandsSize; i++) {
      String value = commands.get(i);
      System.out.println(value);
    }
} else if((input.substring(0, 3)).equals("open")) {
...
}
```

Comment: Will the first if statement catch it before it reaches the substring section?

Comment: It will stop in the if block if the length of the input is not equal to 4. As written above, it will just print out some text and continue to the next substring section. Depending on what you want you could either but the next if as an `else if`, exit from inside the initial if etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is erroring out on the substring method because if the string is less than 4 characters, the method is going outside the bounds of the string (or the char array that makes up the string). You will also want to check that you string is not null before calling methods on the string object.

To have the same flow as you currently have, but to protect your code against the substring error and not being null, you can do this:

```
if(input != null && input.equals("help")){
     //some code
} else if((input != null && input.length() >= 4) && (input.substring(0, 4)).equals("open")) {
    //some code
}
```